# Numpy array: iterate through column and change value based on the current value and the next value

Tags: python, numpy, iteration

I have an array like this:
This is an extension of a recent question that I asked elsewhere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70176293/numpy-array-iterate-through-column-and-change-value-depending-on-the-next-value). I have a numpy array like this:

```
data = np.array([
     [1,2,3],
     [1,2,3],
     [1,2,101],
     [4,5,111],   
     [4,5,6], 
     [4,5,6], 
     [4,5,101], 
     [4,5,112], 
     [4,5,6], 
     ])
```

In the third column, I want the value to be replaced with 10001 if the next one along is `101` AND if the current one is `6`. which would result in an array like this:

```
data = np.array([
     [1,2,3],
     [1,2,3],
     [1,2,101],
     [4,5,111],   
     [4,5,6], 
     [4,5,10001], 
     [4,5,101], 
     [4,5,112], 
     [4,5,6], 
     ])
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way using `numpy.roll`:

```
s = data[:, 2]
data[np.logical_and(s == 6, np.roll(s, -1) == 101), 2] = 10001
```

Output:

```
array([[    1,     2,     3],
       [    1,     2,     3],
       [    1,     2,   101],
       [    4,     5,   111],
       [    4,     5,     6],
       [    4,     5, 10001],
       [    4,     5,   101],
       [    4,     5,   112],
       [    4,     5,     6]])
```

Answer (score 0):

i also came up with a working solution in the meantime:

```
data[
    
    (data[:,2] == 6)
    
    & 
      
      (np.roll(data[:,2]==101,-1,0)),2

] = 10001
```